# Make eclipse highligh selected lines just to their last character, not the whole line

Tags: eclipse, colors, highlight, selecteditem

In other IDEs like vscode, when you highlight a line, it gets highlighted to the last character of the line like this:

[image]

But eclipse does this:

[image: Eclipse IDE]

How can I make eclipse just highlight selected to the end of the line? Some fully-selected lines are not readable at all.

Comment: Why is this a problem?

Comment: @DavidM.Karr because "Some fully-selected lines are not readable at all."

Comment: Can you show us what you're talking about?

Comment: @DavidM.Karr I've added two photos. One from another IDE, and one from eclipse. I want eclipse not to highlight the whole line when I press `CTRL+A`. I want it to just highlight to the end of the line.

Comment: You said "selected lines are not readable at all". I still don't know what you mean by this. I certainly don't see that in these pics.

Comment: @DavidM.Karr Look, in the second picture, when I press `CTRL+A`, the background changes to blue. The whole screen is blue. I want the codes to be blue, not the whole screen. Now, look at the first picture. It's what I want in eclipse.

Comment: Ok, well, feel free to create an enhancement request to create a preference setting to control this, although I think it's likely it won't be considered, but I'm just a user like you, so what do I know? You haven't provided any evidence, to me at least, that this provides any value. You said "selected lines are not readable at all", but I see no evidence of this.

Comment: @DavidM.Karr Thanks a lot. About the value: Which one is more readable? A fully BLUE screen or just blue lines?